# Prevent parent expanding when transform:scale() used on child

Tags: html, css

I have a large document (i.e. `5000px : 3000px`) and I need to display it centered in a `800px : 600px` div with potential margins. I decided to use:

```
translate:scale(0.15) translateX(-50%);
left:50%;
```

But the parent `div` is still expanded to the height of 3000px. When I set parent height or/and max-height on 600px and it do resize to given height, but browser window is still 3000px height.

Does any body have a solution to fit the window to its content?

Comment: did you use overflow:hidden to parent

Comment: yes, but it didn't helped

Comment: can you show more of your code ?

Comment: It will be hard, because its a part of a bigger layout. When i tried to write a simple html with those styles it worked properly.

Comment: can you show the working link ? That will be more help full

Comment: unfortunately i can't show it outside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131241/discussion-between-jishnu-v-s-and-julew2).

Comment: use transform-origin:0 0 ; ;)

Comment: @JishnuVS My bad, i have set height and overflow on different ancestors. Overflow hidden now works perfectly :)

Comment: @julew2 i have posted the answer below, if it is worked for you, please tick the answer

Comment: `transform` does not do anything in terms of the overall layout. It simply transforms the individual element to which it is applied, without changing anything else. In particular, the parent element would **not** be recalculated based on the transformed size.

Answer (score 0):

set `height` and add `overflow:hidden` to your css, This wil fix your issue

```
.parent {
   height:400px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```